# Sharepoint 2010 & edit URL page location

Tags: sharepoint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnYjT.jpg)

Is it possible to change the URL of the top link within this navigation? It should redirect to another Sharepoint site.

Comment: Its called the SharePoint Breadcrumb Navigation btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but try setting the portal site connection. If you go to "Site Settings" you'll find "Portal site connection" in the "Site Collection Administration" section. URLs entered there are inserted as the topmost node in the breadcrumb.